# "Could not find JSS app configuration" when deploying JSS app into JSS-SXA Site

Tags: jss

In a JSS with SXA instance...

1. Create JSS Tenant
2. Create JSS Site
3. Attempt to import JSS app using `jss deploy app -c`

Error

```
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Bad Request
Body: Could not find JSS app configuration for 'appname'.
Ensure you have included a configuration patch file for
the JSS app. Running 'jss deploy config' may res
```

This is strange because JSS sites that are managed by SXA **do not need to have configs deployed**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of JSS Site needs to match the app name exactly. Otherwise this error occurs.