# Integrated GraphQL is not working correctly with JSS with SXA

Tags: sxa, jss, graphql

I've been struggling for a few days to get JSS Integrated GraphQL running on an existing SXA project. To rule out any issues being introduced by this project, **I decided to go right back to square one, make a clean install of my Sitecore environment and document each step as I go to reproduce my issue**.

There's a lot of information below, but I believe it's required to get a proper diagnosis.

---

### Sitecore environment setup

I performed a clean install with the following;

- Sitecore.NET 9.2.0 (rev. 002893)
- Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-5.0 for 9.2
- Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.9.0 rev. 190528 for 9.2
- Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.2 XP 12.0.0 rev. 190522

---

### JSS app setup

Following this guide https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-jss-tenant-and-site.html

1. Created JSS Tenant and JSS Site in Sitecore
2. Created an API Key
3. Tested JSS server components with `[host]/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={[api key]}` and getting back the `400 - API key is not valid` error as is expected
4. Used JSS CLI to create a new React site (Node.js v12.13.1)
5. Ran `JSS setup`
6. Copied Deployment Secret to `/sitecore/content/JSS Tenant/JSS Site/Settings`
7. Skipped the config deployment as per documentation
8. Copied the example endpoint config, updated the XML and url param and placed into `\App_Config\Include\zzz`
9. Verified my JSS app runs OK locally with `jss start`
10. Tried to import JSS app to Sitecore using `jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary`, it throws an error;

```cs
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Bad Request
Body: Could not find JSS app configuration for 'jsssxasite'. Ensure you have included or previously installed a configuration patch file for the JSS app. Running 'jss deploy config' may resolve this.
```

Then I remembered reading this article today that my JSS site name should match up *exactly* with the SXA JSS Site name - ["Could not find JSS app configuration" when deploying JSS app into JSS-SXA Site](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/could-not-find-jss-app-configuration-when-deploying-jss-app-into-jss-sxa-site)

1. Created new JSS Site with name that matches my JSS App (jss-sxa-site), deleted old Site with Remove Site script.
2. Tried to import JSS app to Sitecore using `jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary`, it works!

`JSS app build artifacts have been deployed to Sitecore`

---

### Testing out my app

1. The `/home` item from JSS Site opened in Preview and Edit modes just fine
2. Tested the GraphQL endpoint I created earlier (in the config) through the GraphiQL GUI (incognito mode) using the query below and it works, I get back the expected data

```cs
{
 item(path: "/sitecore/content/JSS Tenant/jss-sxa-site/home") {
   id
   path
   children {
     name
   }
   template {
      fields {
       name
     }
   }
 }
}
```

3. I tried to open `home/graphql` page from my app in in Edit or Preview mode, it throws an error:

```cs
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined at GraphQLIntegratedDemo
```

I found this article [Integrated GraphQL is not executed in Experience Editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23546/sxajss-sitecore-first-integrated-graphql-is-not-executed-in-experience-editor)

1. Tried setting the `Layout service configuration` from `sxa-jss` to `jss` inside the JSS Site settings.
2. Got the same error when opening the page again:

```cs
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasource' of undefined at GraphQLIntegratedDemo
```

Well done for getting this far!! :-)

Did I find a bug? Or did I just miss something?

Comment: Regardless of SXA, you need to define your app via a config file. The SXA multi site manager doesn’t work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Are you referring to the config deployment? (step 7 in the 'JSS App Setup')?

Comment: @JKD please navigate to sitecore/content/JSS Tenant/JSS Site/Settings and check what value is set up into "Layout service configuration" field?

Comment: Thanks for that Vadzim.. I came back to work after the Christmas break and got this working after following Marks advice! I will update my question with the answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem that falls on the unfortunate spot in between SXA, JSS, and Sitecore Services Client. I know it doesn't help you to know that these are somewhat separate development teams inside Sitecore, but I do believe that's where this falls.

Using the new SXA/JSS features in 9.2 and above, we've also found that some Api calls and GraphQL calls fail to work correctly on an SXA-only configured JSS app. The workaround for us (as you found to be working as well) was to do an "old style" manual configuration of the JSS app.

I don't believe it should be necessary and am inclined to see this as a bug. For now however, this is the workaround.