# Sitecore JavaScript Rendering SDK (JSS) for Next.js. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'datasource' of 'props.fields.data' as it is undefined

Tags: graphql, nextjs, jss-rendering-sdk

**Issue: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'datasource' of 'props.fields.data' as it is undefined.**

- Sitecore Experience Platform 10.2 (Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) PowerShell module)
- Sitecore Headless Services CD WDP for Sitecore XP
- Sitecore Experience Edge Connector for Sitecore 10.2.0 XP 20.0.0
- Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.2.0 rev. 04247
- Create a JSS project for the latest versions of JSS and Sitecore
  “npx create-sitecore-jss@ver20”

Local certificate has been created successfully and deployed the app by following this command.

```
jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate xx:yyetc.
```

Backend successfully created the

```
/sitecore/templates/Foundation/JavaScript Services/App
```

I can run the app on `localhost:3000` also can be accessed through newly created url

```
https://my-first-jss-app.dev.local/
```

Issue: I can see the home page and JSS Styleguide live examples, when I navigate to graphql it throws the below error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'datasource' of 'props.fields.data' as it is undefined.

69 | const { datasource, contextItem } = props.fields.data;
```

Following are my frontend env details:

```
JSS_EDITING_SECRET=Autocreated, SITECORE_API_KEY=filled, SITECORE_API_HOST=losthost created and assigned, GRAPH_QL_ENDPOINT(Empty), FETCH_WITH=REST
```

Backend details

```
JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret = frontend JSS_EDITING_SECRET
```

I have attached the below screen to explain more in details. Please someone shed a light on this issue. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi try looking into this [Integrated GraphQL is not working correctly with JSS with SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23577/integrated-graphql-is-not-working-correctly-with-jss-with-sxa?rq=1)

looking at the details you've provided it seems like there is some problem with the api calls when it is executed in code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).